# mvc 5 forms authentification error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I would like to implement form authorization is my application.

In my controller i set:

```
 FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(loginVm.use_email, loginVm.RememberMe);
```

Then in my view:

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
```

I got my Request.IsAuthenticated always false, so i tried to add those lines below in the webconfig.

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

However, I came across the error:

```
 It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.
```

I am running in debug mode localhost, what should i do to try to make it works according to you

Thanks for your helps

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, somehow i got another web.config file in the view folder so i remove it :), it works fine now

Comment: @UliKöhler: That's not additional detail for the question, but a "no idea why, but it seems to work now"-solution.

Comment: @Deduplicator Hm... interesting standpoint. I have reviewed this now and although it still look a bit strange I think you are right. I'll delete my previous comment.